# WCF Configuration - HTML5

Tags: wcf

I am working in MVC with WCF. I need to connect WCF services from my MVC application as well as from HTML5 pages. Kindly let me know correct way to configure WCF service to connect both.

If am using **HttpGetEnabled = true**, then i can access from MVC project but not from HTML.

Help me to solve this issue

Here is my web.config file for WCF,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>          
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>          
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: All `httpGetEnabled` does is allow clients to get the metadata for the service.  To call the service from HTML you'll need to use a client-side script - AJAX or jQuery or the like.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. When i call WCF from HTML Page using AJAX, i am getting "service call failed" error

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post the code you're using to call the service (and the service's config file).  "Service call failed" doesn't give us anything to go on.

Comment: @Tim, I have added code. Please have a look on it

Comment: Can you provide example ajax call? You should be calling your controller methods and the controller forwarding the call to your wcf service.

Comment: Where have you defined the endpoints for your WCF Service? What binding are you using?

Comment: @Rajesh - OP is using default configuration, which means the endpoint is wherever the .svc file is hosted, and the binding is `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: If you are using a default endpoint which is with basicHttpBinding then are you sure that the request being made from your ajax code is not with respect to webHttpBinding. Would be great if you can inspect your request with Fiddler and post on how the request looks like for more help